# drf-spectacular produce array of dict instead of dict

Tags: python, django, swagger, swagger-codegen, drf-spectacular

This is my GET request with drf-spectacular for swagger generation:

```
@extend_schema(request=None,response=RespondentResponseTransactionalWithQuestionGetSerializer(many=False)
     )
     
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

This is Serializer itself:

```
class RespondentResponseTransactionalWithQuestionGetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    answers = RespondentResponseTransactionalGetSerializer(many=True)
    general_question = GeneralQuestionResultTransactionalPostSerializer(required=False)
```

which I expect to produce an object similar to this:

```
{
  "general_question": {
    "id": 0,
    "value": "string",
    "employee": 0,
    "general_question": 0
  },
  "answers": [
    {
      "employee": 0,
      "activity": 0,
      "fte": 99999,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 2147483647,
          "subdimension": 0
        }
      ],
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "value": "string",
          "custom_field": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But instead of this I getting an array of similar objects according to swagger documentation:

```
[    {
      "general_question": {
        "id": 0,
        "value": "string",
        "employee": 0,
        "general_question": 0
      },
      "answers": [
        {
          "employee": 0,
          "activity": 0,
          "fte": 99999,
          "values": [
            {
              "value": 2147483647,
              "subdimension": 0
            }
          ],
          "custom_fields": [
            {
              "value": "string",
              "custom_field": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
```

Any ideas on how to make it looks properly? I tried many=False, without many but nothing of that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the View:
view was defined as a generic.ListAPIView and not RetrieveView.